# Как пишутся числительные в названиях книг?

Tags: числительные, названия, цифры

Подскажите, пожалуйста, предпочтительное написание числительных в названиях книг: цифрами или словом?
Например: **13 дней на обольщение** или **Тринадцать дней на обольщение**?

Comment: @shampar Пояснение после правки. "Написать число прописью" — вполне даже правильно. https://all_words.academic.ru/75383/прописью

Comment: Не говорю, что это неправильно. Есть и ещё вариант: цифрами или буквами. Слово — кратко и однозначно, нежели пропись.

Comment: Посмотрите: в первом списке у меня последовательно отобраны произведения с возрастанием числительных (десять, одиннадцать, двенадцать...). Названия с "тринадцать" были выделены и помещены на одной строке специально, т. к. именно **эта цифра** присутствует в вопросе. По поводу "Вы" я задала опрос на Мете.

Answer (score 3):

Числительные, которые легко читаются и не имеют рядом с собой специфических дополнений или знаков, в названиях книг обычно пишутся прописью. Посмотрите:

А.Кристи, *Десять негритят*
Пауло Коэльо, *Одиннадцать минут*
Ильф и Петров, *Двенадцать стульев*

С.Я.Маршак, *Двенадцать месяцев*
Фазиль Искандер, *Тринадцатый подвиг Геракла*

Андрей Саломатов, *Тринадцать*
 Ю.Семенов, *Семнадцать мгновений весны*
А.Дюма, *Двадцать лет спустя*
*Али-Баба и сорок разбойников* (арабская сказка)
Маркес Габриель Гарсиа, *Сто лет одиночества*

Если числительное состоит из нескольких слов да еще с уточнениями, обычно в названии используются цифры:

Рэй Брэдбери, *451° по Фаренгейту*
Джордж Оруэлл, *1984*
Жюль Верн, *20 тысяч лье под водой*
Агата Кристи, *В 4.50 из Паддингтона*
Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие, *Полдень. XXII век*
Дмитрий Ермаков, Анастасия Осипова, *Метро 2033: Третья сила*
Дин Кунц, *Улица Теней, 77*
Джозеф Хеллер, *Уловка-22*
Дэвид Митчелл, *Сон №9*
Валентин Пикуль, *Реквием каравану PQ-17*
Джей Эшер, *13 причин почему*

Это не четкие правила, а наблюдения, поэтому вы вольны выбрать книге любое из названий. Однако, если вы взяли название книги из кусочка текста, то лучше его написать на обложке так, как есть в тексте.

[**Книги с числительными в названиях**](https://www.livelib.ru/selection/10359-knigi-s-chislitelnymi-v-nazvaniyah#books)

**Дополнение**

Вот названия книг, начинающихся именно с цифр:

В. Поротников, *300 спартанцев*
Д. Смит, *101 далматинец*
Стивен Кинг, *11/22/63*
Анна Гавальда, *35 кило надежды*
Фредерик Бегбедер, *99 франков*
Хулио Кортасар, *62. Модель для сборки*
Павел Сутин, *9 дней*
Стивен Р. Кови, *7 навыков высокоэффективных людей. Мощные инструменты развития личности*
*1000 и одна ночь* (сборник сказок)
Алина Деллис, *86400* секунд счастья
[**Цифры и числа в названиях произведений**](https://www.livelib.ru/selection/386963-tsifry-ili-chisla-v-nazvaniyah-proizvedenij/~3#books)

Answer (score 0):

***[Книги с числительными в названиях](https://www.livelib.ru/selection/10359-knigi-s-chislitelnymi-v-nazvaniyah)***; ***[Книги, в названии которых есть порядковые, собирательные и количественные числительные](https://www.livelib.ru/selection/526424-knigi-v-nazvanii-kotoryh-est-poryadkovye-sobiratelnye-i-kolichestvennye-chislitelnye)***.

---

В Вашем случае - "Тринадцать дней на обольщение".

В примерах, приведённых Риммой, все, за одним исключением, случаи числительных цифрами - это градусы, номера, год-шифр (1984), адреса...

А исключение - переводная книга Джей Эшер "13 причин почему" - редакторская ошибка или оплошность.